# Application and relevance of Sobolev gradients

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

The Sobolev gradient concept has been developed in the 1970s, with a first publication in 1985, and an introduction can be found at: [Ranka](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~renka/papers/sobolev.pdf)

I would like to learn how strong the impact of Sobolev gradients has been in numerical partial differential equations.

Is it one of several possible tools for nonlinear pde, or a powerful approach without "competitors"?

Comment: The link seems broken.

Comment: For whatever reason ... Well, thanks for the advice. It is corrected now.